# HTTP Post response in Typescript to update google spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I am updating spreadsheets from google API at the following url: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append

In the update form I am filling in the following properties:
in the spreadsheetId field I put the ID of the spreadsheet and in the range field the name of the sheet, in the insertDataOption field I choose INSERT_ROWS, in valueInputOption, RAW and in the Request body field the following **object**:

```
{
  "values": [
    [
      "id",
      "ser",
      "IP",
      "host",
      "type",
      "auth"
    ],
    [
      "1",
      null,
      null,
      "",
      "Web",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "2",
      null,
      "191.174.230.02",
      "",
      "Proxy",
      ""
    ]
  ]
}
```

The HTTP Post response is as follows: POST [https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[spreadsheetId-lex.europa.eu/values/[range-lex.europa.eu:append](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/%5BspreadsheetId-lex.europa.eu/values/%5Brange-lex.europa.eu:append)

**My problem**: how can I form the HTTP Post response with the properties and the object that I want to add? That is, how do I tell the response what data I want to add in the spreadsheet?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what do you want to do exactly? Just to add that data to the end of a spreadsheet? Where does typescript come into it? Do you want to do it with the `fetch` api? Or do you just want to know how to structure the request body?

Comment: @iansedano I want to know how I can do the same as I do from the API URL (deveolpers.google.com), in the Typescript code. Build the HTTP response with the same properties and the request body object

Comment: Where are you running the Typescript from? The browser (client side)?

Comment: @iansedano From the server side with Node JS

Comment: In addition to spreadsheetId you must the query parameters range=A1:F&valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED , and it will work with the object body you specified

Comment: @Goran What I have currently works from the URL of developers.google.com, my problem is how to build the HTTP response to update the spreadsheet with the same data but from the Typescript code

Comment: Are you using Axios? Do you have any code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to append data to a Spreadsheet with Node

Note: This does not use Typescript, but since plain JavaScript is also valid Typescript, this should work for your Typescript project.

#### First steps

Follow the [Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs). This will get your project set up with:

- GCP project
- API activation
- OAuth consent screen
- Credentials - be sure to download this and save as `credentials.json` in the project folder.

It will also get you to install the Node.js library:

```
npm install googleapis
```

#### Making a request

Below is code that is adapted from the quickstart to use an `append` request:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// =============
// AUTHORIZATION
// =============

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), append);
});

function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

// =============
//    APPEND
// =============

function append(auth){
    const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
        spreadsheetId: '13rdolwpUD4h4RTuExxxxxx', 
        range: 'Sheet1!A1', 
        valueInputOption: 'RAW',
        insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',  
        resource: {
            "values": [
                [
                  "id",
                  "ser",
                  "IP",
                  "host",
                  "type",
                  "auth"
                ],
                [
                  "1",
                  null,
                  null,
                  "",
                  "Web",
                  ""
                ],
                [
                  "2",
                  null,
                  "191.174.230.02",
                  "",
                  "Proxy",
                  ""
                ]
              ]
        },
    })
}
```

Be sure to replace the spreadsheet ID with your one.

When you run this for the first time with `node .` then you should be prompted to go to a URL to get the auth code for the OAuth flow. Once you are authorized, then the script should execute.

#### Reference

- [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs)
- [Append examples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append#examples)

Comment: Ok, this is what I wanted, to know how to form the HTTP response. This format also works to clear the contents of the spreadsheet using batchClear?

Comment: Yes it will be a similar format but check the documentation for the example. Also, autocomplete in your IDE can be very helpful too

Comment: Can you help me with the other question I have ?, about how to get the data from the google API

Comment: It will be similar to the above `sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({...})` https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get

Comment: I am doing it from the API v3 which is the only one that worked for me to pass the parameters. But I have trouble forming it

Comment: v3 is deprecated, you need to change to v4 from this month

Comment: The problem with v4 is that I can't get all the properties I need like the modified date. In the API v3 if it returns all those parameters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236345/discussion-between-iansedano-and-print).